# inline listings line wrapping issues

Tags: listings, line-breaking

I am having issues with inline listings line wrapping. As you can see in the linked image, the period ending the sentence is on the next line due to wrapping of the `cite-website` text. The listings package decided to wrap the text even though the whole of it is on the first line. If the red hook-arrow was not there, the period would fit there.

[image: listings wrapping issues image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{microtype}
\UseMicrotypeSet[protrusion]{basicmath} % disable protrusion for tt fonts
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[vmargin=1in,headheight=13pt,twoside,twocolumn,a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{accsupp}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor}

\newcommand{\noncopy}[1]{%
    \BeginAccSupp{method=escape,ActualText={}}%
    #1%
    \EndAccSupp{}%
}

\lstset{breaklines=true,
  xleftmargin=1.5em,framexleftmargin=1em,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  upquote=true,
  literate={`}{{\BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText=`}‵\EndAccSupp{}}}1
  {"}{{\BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText="}"\EndAccSupp{}}}1
  {'}{{\BeginAccSupp{method=plain,ActualText='}'\EndAccSupp{}}}1,
  showstringspaces=false,
  numbers=left, numberstyle=\scriptsize\noncopy,
  %postbreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\noncopy{\ensuremath{\color{red}\hookrightarrow}}},
  prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\noncopy{\ensuremath{\color{red}\rhookswarrow}}}
}

\begin{document}
Foo bar baaz \lstinline!cite-website!.
\end{document}
```

**UPDATE 1**

Here is smaller MWE. I am keeping the above in the post because I am actually using all those things in the actual document:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage[vmargin=1in,headheight=13pt,twoside,twocolumn,a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{MnSymbol}
\usepackage{textcomp}

\lstset{breaklines=true,
  basicstyle=\ttfamily,
  showstringspaces=false,
  prebreak=\raisebox{0ex}[0ex][0ex]{\ensuremath{\rhookswarrow}}}

\begin{document}
Foo bar baaz \lstinline!cite-website!.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Although this doesn't solve the issue with `listings`, have you had a look at [`minted`](http://ctan.org/pkg/minted)?  It is a pretty good package to highlight code.  Also, if you're inserting a URL, you could use `\url` provided by [`hyperref`](http://ctan.org/pkg/hyperref).

Comment: @JP-Ellis: Well, I am using `org-mode` which I convert to LaTeX using Pandoc. It supports minted highlighting by default but the last time I tried it was not wrapping long lines, which is something I need.

Comment: @JP-Ellis: The [`cite-website`](https://github.com/wilx/cite-website/) is actually a name of a tool that I have created.

Comment: Yeah, `\mintinline` doesn't support line breaks because it is intended to be use to single keywords.  If you have snippets of code which are quite long, then perhaps you want them in their own small listings instead of having them inline?

Answer (score 1):

I've just begun experimenting with `listings`. Have you tried adding this line to your `\lstset` definition?

```
breakatwhitespace=true,
```

This setting determines whether automatic breaks should only happen at whitespace (I think by default they can happen anywhere in a line, to accommodate people who are writing types of code without much whitespace in it.)

Source: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Source_Code_Listings#Settings